# Alteryx Designer vs MS SQL Server aggregation differences

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions, alteryx

I am working on converting a data pipeline that runs on Alteryx Designer into a MS SQL Server query, and I am noticing that I get different results when I use the GROUP BY step.
For example, both processes read from the same table that has 2,318,794 rows, but when I use aggregate functions (GROUP BY, MAX(), COUNT() and SUM()) they Alteryx process returns 2,089,738 rowsand the SQL query returns 2,089,238 (a 500 row difference) and the difference increases the more I aggregate, to the point that by the end of the process I end with a 60k lines difference between what Alteryx returns and what my query returns.

Is there a difference on how Alteryx and MS SQL Server execute aggreation operations? Or how they handle NULL values when aggregating?

Any input or idea is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to answer you without the query, the table DDL and of course a set of test values.

But one thing you must understand, is that SQL apply rules about some datatypes that can be different in other systems. I do not know what Alteryx Designer is, but, as an SQL expert and formerly a SQL Server MVP, I suspect this product to not conforms to the standard ISO SQL.

Percularly with strings that can contains trailing spaces that is ignored by SQL...
That is, some VARCHAR data can have space chars at the end, that will be distinct rows in Alteryx and fuse by the GROUP BY operator in SQL !